# Simplifying jquery / javascript for checkbox links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, dry

I have written a couple simple lines of code that allows checkboxes in a sidebar navigation when clicked to send the user to a specified link. The checkboxes work as filters.
here is the HTML for the checkbox:

```
<li class="inactive" aria-selected="false">
<input id="path1" type="checkbox" value="Accessories">
<a href="href">Accessories</a>
</li>
```

And the jquery / javascript that creates the interaction:

```
    $('#path1').click(function(){ 
                 window.location='href'; //href would be a unique link
   });
```

The issue isn't getting this interaction to work, I'm having a logic problem. The way it's written is it's targeting the id of the checkbox. It isn't scalable. 8 links aren't so bad, but 500 links, each one unique, you get the idea.

Is there a solution that targets every checkbox but allows for unique links for each one? I.e. targeting the class makes all of the checkboxes have the same href, so that isn't an option, etc.

Comment: from where 'href' will come?

Comment: `$("input[type='checkbox]'").click(....)` Also, what does this have to do with "minification", which the refactoring of code to condense it to the smallest amount of bytes?

Comment: 'href' is a stand-in for the link. So it could be something like '/products/valves/' when clicked, but there are a number of check-boxes, each going to a different place, I thought it would muck up the example to use actual links.

Comment: Perhaps minification was the wrong term. I thought it would be correct though, as the goal is to take what would be 50 blocks of almost identical code down to about 5 or 6 lines for a single block, hopefully.

Comment: That's DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself). Minification is something else.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I changed the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-custom-click="href">
```

The above code can be repeated many times as you need and enables you to have as many number of checkboxes as you want.

Note `href` in the above HTML represents your link for that specific checkbox.

And the one liner JavaScript:

```
$("input[data-custom-click]").click(function (){
    window.location=$(this).attr("data-custom-click");
});
```

The selector `input[data-custom-click]` will select all your custom behaviour checkboxes and the `$(this)` selects the clicked checkbox.

Comment: This looks good. I'll test but it makes sense it would most likely work.

Comment: Can you provide a js fiddle of your code so that i can debug it from there?

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you! First time dealing with DRY this helped me a lot moving forward.

Comment: Was my fault, didn't properly activate the code using document ready.

Comment: @TrevorJones That's great! It solved your problem and also simplified the HTML. If you need any other help with web(php/WordPress backed) I am happy to help 

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `href` value comes from the link that follows the input you can use:

```
$('li.inactive input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){ 
    window.location = $(this).next('a').attr('href')
});
```

Comment: Have I placed my href in the wrong place? Are you saying I need to place it elsewhere and target it with the code you've provided?